# How can I receive multipart/form-data in web api 2 on OWIN pipeline

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, owin, multipartform-data

I'm having trouble getting my web api 2 method to correctly read my multipart/form-data post from ng-file-upload on the angular UI side.

I'm initiating the call like so:

```
Upload.upload({
                url: config.ApiUrl + 'Orders/CreateOrder',
                data: request
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log('Success ' + response.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + response.data);
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.errors = "Oops! Something went wrong... " + error.statusText;
            });
```

And this gets me a payload to send to web api:

```
-----------------------------9623122368016
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="somefield"

Some Value
-----------------------------9623122368016
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="errorMessage"

null
-----------------------------9623122368016
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success"

false
-----------------------------9623122368016
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="imapdf.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.2
1 0 obj 
<<
/Producer()
/Author()
/Title()
/Subject()
/Keywords()
/CreationDate(D:20040106)
/ModDate(D:20040106)
/Creator()
>> 
endobj
2 0 obj 
<<
/Type/XObject
/Subtype/Image
/Name/wpt1
/Width 41
/Height 15
/BitsPerComponent 8
/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB
/Length 100
/Filter [/FlateDecode] >>
stream
xsqH0s
```

I can't access `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files`because I'm using the OWIN pipeline, and am not having much luck with `Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync`

How can I receive my file & it's associated form data in web api 2?

C# Code Update:

```
public Task<OrderRequest> CreateOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest)
{
    try
    {
        var asdf = OwinHttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetOwinContext(Request);
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("multipart/form-data"))
        {
            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            this.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            var content = provider.Contents.First();
            var buffer = content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        }

        var test = orderRequest;
        var a = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return Task.FromResult<OrderRequest>(null);
}
```

Comment: @Kirk Larkin Sure, I posted my code, in my case the ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider) is coming back null on the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its name suggests, `ReadAsMultipartAsync` is an *asynchronous* function. Because you're not awaiting the call, you're likely ending up in a situation where you're trying to access `Contents` before it has been populated.

To fix this, you can update your `CreateOrder` action as follows:

```
public async Task<OrderRequest> CreateOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest)
{
    ...
    await this.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    ...
}
```

All that's changed here is the addition of `async` before `Task<OrderRequest>` and `await` before `this.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);`. You'll also want to add `await` before `content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();` for the same reason and then you can just `return null` rather than having to use `Task.FromResult` at the end.

In fact, here's the entire code with those changes:

```
public async Task<OrderRequest> CreateOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest)
{
    try
    {
        var asdf = OwinHttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetOwinContext(Request);
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("multipart/form-data"))
        {
            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            await this.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            var content = provider.Contents.First();
            var buffer = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        }

        var test = orderRequest;
        var a = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Obviously, this is not a complete solution but I believe it will address your specific problems and allow you to continue your exploration.